# webservice method repeats itself more than once when clicking on button

Tags: web-services, xamarin.android, asmx, floating-action-button

i have created an android app via xamarin.android. i have a recyclerview that gets its data from an asmx webservice. the recyclerview is filled correctly. i also have a floatingActionButton that deletes rows from the recyclerview, and floatingActionButton save that saves the data that is in the recyclerview in a database table in sqlserver. this is the code:

```
 private void Presave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (laborers_dt_total.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this.Context, "select the laborers that you need!", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            }
            else
            {
                
                ws.get_labors_of_todayAsync(0, "", 3);
                ws.get_labors_of_todayCompleted += Ws_get_labors_of_todayCompleted;
                supp_status = 1;

            }


         
        }
        private void Ws_get_labors_of_todayCompleted(object sender, WSattendane1.get_labors_of_todayCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.Context);
          List<String> repeated_laborers = new List<String>();
          DataTable labors_today = new DataTable();
          labors_today = e.Result;
           
            try
            {

                for(int i=0;i<laborers_dt_total.Rows.Count;i++)
                {

                   for (int j = 0; j < labors_today.Rows.Count; j++)
                  {
                      if(laborers_dt_total.Rows[i]["laborerCode"].ToString() == labors_today.Rows[j]["laborerCode"].ToString())
                      {
                         repeated_laborers.Add(laborers_dt_total.Rows[i]["laborerName"].ToString());
                      }

                  }

            }
                string message = "";
               if (repeated_laborers.Count > 0)
            {

                  for (int i = 0; i < repeated_laborers.Count; i++)
                 {
                       message = message + repeated_laborers[i] + ", ";
                  }

                  alert.SetTitle(Resources.GetText(Resource.String.repeated_names));
                 alert.SetMessage(message + Resources.GetText(Resource.String.exits_else_where));
                  alert.SetPositiveButton(Resources.GetText(Resource.String.ok), (senderAlert, args) =>
                 {
                     _dialog.Dismiss();
              });
                   _dialog = alert.Create();
                  _dialog.Show();

              }
              else if (repeated_laborers.Count==0)
              {
                   Toast.MakeText(context, "uuydsa", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                ws.presave_scheduleAsync(laborers_dt_total, user.sch_code, DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString(), project_code, int.Parse(phase_order), "SCH", "SCH", "", userid, int.Parse(department_code), int.Parse(department_code), 0, supp_status, user.create_update);
                  ws.presave_scheduleCompleted += Ws_presave_scheduleCompleted;
                 presave.ClearFocus();

             }


            }
           catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException exp)
            {
              System.Net.WebException exception = new System.Net.WebException("can't reach server", exp.InnerException);
             Toast.MakeText(this.Context, exp.InnerException.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
              Context context = this.Context;
             alert.SetTitle("Connection failed");
              alert.SetMessage("Please, Check your Internet Connection!");
              alert.SetPositiveButton("Retry", (senderAlert, args) =>
               {
              ws.get_labors_of_todayAsync(0, "", 3);
                ws.get_labors_of_todayCompleted += Ws_get_labors_of_todayCompleted;

               alert.Dispose();
           });

              _dialog = alert.Create();

                _dialog.Show();
            }


        }
```

the problem is that on each click on presave, the function       `ws.get_labors_of_todayCompleted += Ws_get_labors_of_todayCompleted;` repeats itself "number of presave clicks" times. i removed all the code inside it and added just a toast. on each click, the toast is displayed "number of presave clicks" times. i click it for the first time, the toast appears once, then i click it again, the toast repeats itself twice, and so on. what is the problem? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> private void Presave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>         if (laborers_dt_total.Rows.Count == 0)
>         {
>             Toast.MakeText(this.Context, "select the laborers that you need!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
>
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             
>             ws.get_labors_of_todayAsync(0, "", 3);
>             ws.get_labors_of_todayCompleted += Ws_get_labors_of_todayCompleted;
>             supp_status = 1;
>
>         }    
>     }
> ```

From your code ,we can find there is an `if` statement,if the first condition `laborers_dt_total.Rows.Count == 0`  does not satisfy the condition,then it will go to execute the following code:

```
    {
        ws.get_labors_of_todayAsync(0, "", 3);
        ws.get_labors_of_todayCompleted += Ws_get_labors_of_todayCompleted;
        supp_status = 1;
    }
```

So, if the condition `laborers_dt_total.Rows.Count == 0` is not always satisfied, it is nomal on each click on presave, the function `ws.get_labors_of_todayCompleted += Ws_get_labors_of_todayCompleted`; repeats itself "number of presave clicks" times.

In summary, you can recheck the value of `laborers_dt_total.Rows.Count` .

In addition, if you don't want to execute event `Presave_Click`after your first clicking this button, you can use [Xamarin.Forms ActivityIndicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/activityindicator) to achieve this. which displays an animation to show that the application is engaged in a lengthy activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would just change:

```
{
        ws.get_labors_of_todayAsync(0, "", 3);
        ws.get_labors_of_todayCompleted += Ws_get_labors_of_todayCompleted;
        supp_status = 1;
}
```

to:

```
{
        ws.get_labors_of_todayAsync(0, "", 3);
        ws.get_labors_of_todayCompleted -= Ws_get_labors_of_todayCompleted;
        ws.get_labors_of_todayCompleted += Ws_get_labors_of_todayCompleted;
        supp_status = 1;
}
```

This will ensure your don't keep accumulating method calls.